# Can I sue a company in US even if I'm in Brazil?

Tags: privacy, civil-law, civil-procedure, brazil

I currently live in Brazil and bought a **Lifetime** VPN service from a company called `Spyproof VPN` in 13 Oct 2015 which supposedly does not keep logs. After investigating some more, I found out that the `Privacy Policy` and `Terms of Service`links had gone missing and before when they did exist, they didn't point anywhere, meaning that they never had them in the start.

Recently I de-compiled their VPN Client and saw that they retrieve the HWID which is the processor ID that is unique to every processor, thus allowing them to log all my actions, even though they already have a login + password combination.

The password is also sent in plain text with no encryption or whatsoever by the internet, not even https.

I then opened a support ticket asking them why were they retrieving that information and today 2 weeks after having opened the support ticket, I tried to log into their service and as it appears, my login doesn't exists.

My next step is to go after paypal to start a dispute and then attempt to sue them.

My question is: Can I sue them even though I'm in another country?

A possible second question would be: Can I sue them for the proof and reasons I have?

P.S.: If necessary I can post the pictures where they state that they do not hold logs and the picture of the code from the VPN client where they send the HWID in EVERY request together with the plain text password.

Comment: This honestly sounds like something you should try and talk to a lawyer about. You definitely can sue them, and it's incredibly likely that there is a civil liability at hand here. Depending on what they did, there may be criminal acts here as well - so you may want to try and report it somewhere (unfortunately, I'm not sure where).

Comment: You may be able to sue them - but is it worth it?  The company is probably a shell with no assets, you will have lots of costs to get to court etc.  Assuming that like most of these, you paid < $50 for the access, did you really expect to get Liftime access - and how do you think they were going to pay for the service.  Also, why would you use a VPN service not based on a standard protocol like OpenVPN?

Comment: Another obstacle - if you do try and sue them, you first need to find them - and, looking at their website, and bearing in mind their business, I think you are looking at an uphill battle to even find what country they are based in - let alone where to serve them.  I hate to say this (I like a good fight), but, past disputing it with Paypal, write it off to a learning experience

Comment: Yeah, I realized what I had done after it and regretted, but as the service worked fine and I didn't knew the flaws it had I though it was ok. I'm currently opening a dispute with PayPal and maybe try to see if I can get the forum where they were advertising to ban them (and maybe PayPal too?).

Comment: "Lifetime access" is almost exactly like a Ponzi scheme. They can only afford to keep your account open as long as they keep getting new members into the  pool. I know not entirely true, they could take the money, invest and use profits to stay afloat, but come on.

Comment: Yes, but in most online games you buy it and you can play online as long as the servers are up. I started from the same principle when I bought it. My main deception was the way their system was designed: sending passwords without encryption and holding logs (apparently).